# truffle unbox pet-shop gives DownloadingError: read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)

Tags: truffle, error

Ubuntu 18.04.

Truffle v5.1.2 (core: 5.1.2)

Solidity v0.5.12 (solc-js)

Node v13.2.0

Web3.js v1.2.2

---

When I execute truffle unbox pet-shop on terminal, I get error

```
✔ Preparing to download
⠼ DownloadingError: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)
```

I am expecting contents of directory to look like this (from https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/the-ultimate-ethereum-dapp-tutorial)

[image]

Instead it looks like this,

[image]

And I didn't see issue on Github (I just created one, https://github.com/truffle-box/pet-shop-box/issues/49).

And I get same error when I run

`truffle init`

Can you help me straighten this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind organizational proxy, clone the git repo.

In the case of truffle pet-shop

```
git clone https://github.com/truffle-box/pet-shop-box.git
cd pet-shop-box
rm -rf .git # Remove the .git record 
npm install
```